# cleaning strings for link urls in python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So i have beautiful soup code which visit the main the main page of a website
and scrapes the links there. However when I get  the links in python I can't seem to clean up the link (after it's converted to a string) for concatenation with the root url.

```
import re
import requests
import bs4

list1=[]

def get_links():

    regex3= re.compile('/[a-z\-]+/[a-z\-]+')
    response = requests.get('http://noisetrade.com')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    links=  soup.select('div.grid_info  a[href]')
    for link in links:
       lk= link.get('href')
       prtLk= regex3.findall(lk)
       list1.append(prtLk)


def visit_pages():
    url1=str(list1[1])
    print(url)

get_links()
visit_pages()
```

produces output: "['/stevevantinemusic/unsolicited-material']"

desired output:"/stevevantinemusic/unsolicited-material"

I have tried .strip() and .replace() and re.sub/match/etc. . . I can't seem to isolate the chars '[,\',]' which are the characters I need removed, I had iterated through it with sub-strings but that feels inefficient. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

`findall` returns a list of results so you can either write:

```
for link in links:
    lk = link.get('href')    
    urls = regex3.findall(lk)   
    if urls:
        prtLk = urls[0]
        list1.append(prtLk)
```

or better, use `search` method:

```
for link in links:
    lk = link.get('href')    
    m = regex3.search(lk)
    if m:
        prtLk = m.group()
        list1.append(prtLk)
```

Those brackets were the result of converting a list with one element to a string. 
For example:

```
l = ['text']
str(l)
```

results in:

```
"['text']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I use the regexp `r'[\[\'\]]'` to replace any of the unwanted characters with the empty string:

```
$ cat pw.py
import re

def visit_pages():
    url1="['/stevevantinemusic/unsolicited-material']"
    url1 = re.sub(r'[\[\'\]]','',url1)
    print(url1)

visit_pages()

$ python pw.py
/stevevantinemusic/unsolicited-material
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I think you are trying to do:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> with open('noise.html', 'r') as f:
...     lines = f.read()
... 
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(lines)
>>> root_url = 'http://noisetrade.com'
>>> for link in soup.select('div.grid_info a[href]'):
...     print(root_url + link.get('href'))
... 
http://noisetrade.com/stevevantinemusic
http://noisetrade.com/stevevantinemusic/unsolicited-material
http://noisetrade.com/jessicarotter
http://noisetrade.com/jessicarotter/winter-sun
http://noisetrade.com/geographermusic
http://noisetrade.com/geographermusic/live-from-the-el-rey-theatre
http://noisetrade.com/kaleo
http://noisetrade.com/kaleo/all-the-pretty-girls-ep
http://noisetrade.com/aviddancer
http://noisetrade.com/aviddancer/an-introduction
http://noisetrade.com/thinkr
http://noisetrade.com/thinkr/quiet-kids-ep
http://noisetrade.com/timcaffeemusic
http://noisetrade.com/timcaffeemusic/from-conversations
http://noisetrade.com/pearl
http://noisetrade.com/pearl/hello
http://noisetrade.com/staceyrandolmusic
http://noisetrade.com/staceyrandolmusic/fables-noisetrade-sampler
http://noisetrade.com/sleepyholler
http://noisetrade.com/sleepyholler/sleepy-holler
http://noisetrade.com/sarahmcgowanmusic
http://noisetrade.com/sarahmcgowanmusic/indian-summer
http://noisetrade.com/briandunne
http://noisetrade.com/briandunne/songs-from-the-hive
```

Remember also bs4 has its own types that it uses.

A good way to debug your scripts would be to place:

```
for link in links:
   import pdb;pdb.set_trace() # the script will stop for debugging here
   lk= link.get('href')
   prtLk= regex3.findall(lk)
   list1.append(prtLk)
```

Anywhere you want to debug.

And then you could do something like this within `pdb`:

```
next
l
print(type(lk))
print(links)
dir()
dir(links)
dir(lk)
```

Comment: Also `pdb` is the python equivalent of `gdb` for c++.